# Can we create a xml file with specific node with Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-xml

I have another question about Spark and Scala. I want to use that technologie to get data and generate a xml.
Therefore, I want to know if it is possible to create node ourself (not automatic creation) and what library can we use ? I search but I found nothing very interesting(Like I'm new in this technologie, I don't know many keywords).
  I want to know if there is in Spark something like this code (I write that in scala. It works in local but I can't use new File() in Spark).

```
val docBuilder: DocumentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
  val document = docBuilder.newDocument()

ar root:Element = document.createElement("<name Balise>")
    attr = document.createAttribute("<attr1>")
    attr.setValue("<value attr1>")
    root.setAttributeNode(<attr>)
    attr = document.createAttribute("<attr2>")
    attr.setValue("<value attr2>")
    root.setAttributeNode(attr)
    document.appendChild(root)
    document.setXmlStandalone(true)

var transformerFactory:TransformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    var transformer:Transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer()
    var domSource:DOMSource = new DOMSource(document)
    var streamResult:StreamResult = new StreamResult(new File(destination))
    transformer.transform(domSource,streamResult)
```

I want to know if it's possible to do that with spark.

Thanks for your answer and have a good day.

Comment: I think spark is not the best tool for you to do this. I would suggest you to use Akka Framework for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but you can do something similar by using Spark XML API pr XStream API on Spark.

First try using [Spark XML API](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) which is most useful when reading and writing XML files using Spark. However, At the time of writing this, Spark XML has following limitations.

```
 1) Adding attribute to root element has not supported.
 2) Does not support following structure where you have header and footer elements. 

  <parent>
       <header></header>
       <dataset> 
          <data attr="1"> suports xml tags and data here</data>
          <data attr="2">value2</data>  
      </dataset>
      <footer></footer>
  </parent>
```

If you have one root element and following data then Spark XML is go to api.

Alternatively, you can look at **XStream API**. Below are steps how to use it to create custom XML structures.

1) First, create a Scala class similar to the structure you wanted in XML.

```
case class XMLData(name:String, value:String, attr:String)
```

2) Create an instance of this class

```
val data = XMLData("bookName","AnyValue", "AttributeValue")
```

3) Conver data object to XML using XStream API. If you already have data in a DataFrame, then do a map transformation to convert data to an XML string and store it back in DataFrame. if you do so, then you can skip step #4

```
val xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver)
val xmlString = xstream.toXML(data)
```

4) Now convert xmlString to DataFrame

```
val df = xmlString.toDF()
```

5) Finally, write to a file

```
df.write.text("file://filename")
```

Here isa full sample example with XStream API

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class Animal(cri:String,taille:Int)

object SparkXMLUsingXStream{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.
    builder.master ("local[*]")
    .appName ("sparkbyexamples.com")
    .getOrCreate ()

    var animal:Animal = Animal("Rugissement",150)
    val xstream1 = new XStream(new DomDriver())
    xstream1.alias("testAni",classOf[Animal])
    xstream1.aliasField("cricri",classOf[Animal],"cri")
    val xmlString = Seq(xstream1.toXML(animal))

    import spark.implicits._
    val newDf = xmlString.toDF()
    newDf.show(false)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Thanks

Comment: Hello Naveen, thanks for your answer. Do you think that with this technologie : http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html , I can have a similar result ?

Comment: Yes, as long as your XML are following XML syntax and semantics. Remember Xstram API is java/scala api not created for Spark. However, we can use it in spark to convert object to xml string.

Comment: Hello, for me the ligne : val df = xmlString.toDF()

Comment: Excuse me I push Enter before I finish my comment.

Comment: Again. How can we return to the line without post a comment ? the ligne `val df = xmlString.toDF()` didn't work. I have the following error : `<console>:36: error: value toDF is not a member of String
       val df = xmlString.toDF()` . Do you know why ? (I can't print xmlString but can't convert). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then with this library, some balises that I don't want are added to the String : `<testAni>
  <cricri>Rugissement</cricri>
  <taille>150</taille>
  <_-outer>
    <_-outer>
      <_-iw reference="../.."/>
      <_-outer>
        <_-iw reference="../.."/>
      </_-outer>
    </_-outer>
  </_-outer>
</testAni>` I dont wan't the outer and reference. Only cricri and taille. (I continue to search on my side).

Comment: Please add your complete new program on this question or on another question, I will correct it and send across to you. I’ve done this in my project and it works well!!!

Comment: `class Animal(cCrie:String,cTaille:Int) {
    var cri:String = cCrie
    var taille:Int = cTaille
}
var animal:Animal = new Animal("Rugissement",150)
val xstream1 = new XStream(new DomDriver())
xstream1.alias("testAni",classOf[Animal])
xstream1.aliasField("cricri",classOf[Animal],"cri")
val xmlString = xstream1.toXML(animal)
val newDf = xmlString.toDF()`

Comment: No I ask for stackOverflow :D.

I still have the two problems that I say before.

Comment: On stackoverlow, indentation works only on questions and answers but not on comments. I've updated my answer with more info and example

Comment: Were you able to progress with the solution?